# How do I get SMS messages to be sorted in chronological order?

Tags: sms, settings, htc-desire-hd

I just got an HTC Desire HD, and it's sorting my SMS texts by what the sender has sent up at the top of the conversation page, and what I reply down below. It's almost like two conversations in chronological order, but it's not mixing them together. When it says I have a new text, it's actually the one I sent them and I have to scroll up to read the reply. How do I get the the SMS conversations to read in an answer-response chronological format?

Comment: This sounds weird. On HTC the default message app does exactly what you want. You sure you are not using a replacement?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how your stock messaging app works, but [HandcentSMS](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms&feature=search_result) does this exact thing, and very well at that!